# If-else command in calculator

Tags: c#

So I'm currently making a calculator for a school project. The point of the calculator is calculating triangles. The user have to provide with 3 pieces of information, either 2 sides and 1 angle or 2 angles and 1 side.

As you can see in my piece of code provided below, I have no clue how to proceed with my project. I'm pretty new to C#. 
I have to check so that if A,B and c has been provided it has to calculate this, and if A,B and b is provided it has to calculate this and so on. But I'm unsure how I do the "if-else" command.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<double> angles = new List<double>();
        List<double> sides = new List<double>();
        double A = (AAngle.Text == "") ? 0.00 : Convert.ToDouble(AAngle.Text);
        double B = (BAngle.Text == "") ? 0.00 : Convert.ToDouble(BAngle.Text);
        double C = (CAngle.Text == "") ? 0.00 : Convert.ToDouble(CAngle.Text);
        double a = (ASide.Text == "") ? 0.00 : Convert.ToDouble(ASide.Text);
        double b = (BSide.Text == "") ? 0.00 : Convert.ToDouble(BSide.Text);
        double c = (CSide.Text == "") ? 0.00 : Convert.ToDouble(CSide.Text);
        if (!(A == 0.00))
            angles.Add(A);
        if (!(B == 0.00))
            angles.Add(B);
        if (!(C == 0.00))
            angles.Add(C);
        if (!(a == 0.00))
            sides.Add(a);
        if (!(b == 0.00))
            sides.Add(b);
        if (!(c == 0.00))
            sides.Add(c);
        if ((angles.Count() == 2 && sides.Count == 1) || (angles.Count == 1 && sides.Count == 2))
        {
           if ???
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("NOT ENOUGH OR TOO MANY SIDES/ANGLES PROVIDED OR NOT A VALID TRIANGLE");
        }
    }
```

Comment: _"it has to calculate this"_ You haven't told us what `this` actually is. What do you want to calculate and where did you stuck??

Comment: Just like in the last question - which you deleted - the answer is: Learn the math. This really hasn't to do anything with C#. How to do if-else you already know, you use it already in your code. It is *your* school project, not ours. We can help you with a concrete problem. But currently, you are basically asking us to write the project for you.

Comment: Your code already contains the valid `if-else` example. If it is not enough, you should have googled [C# if](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=c%23+if&aq=f&oq=c%23+if&aqs=chrome.0.57j58j62l3.1417&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and the first or second link would give you [answer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: I don't have a problem with the math. I just need to know how to do the if command, what "this" is isn't really relevant.
I just need to know how to make the if-else command, where if I have A,B and a it has to perform a calculation, what the calculation is, isn't really relevant for this step yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an else if statement like this one:

```
    if (angles.Count() == 2 && sides.Count == 1)
    {
       // calculate based on two angles and one side
    }
    else if (angles.Count == 1 && sides.Count == 2)
    {
       // calculate based on one angle and two sides
    }
    else
    {
       MessageBox.Show(...)
    }
```

Comment: This is somewhat, what I need.
`if (A.Count && B.Count && c.Count)`
{ 
  // Calculation
}

Answer (score 0):

You can try the C# if-else reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5011f09h.aspx).

Try writing the code yourself. if it's not working as expected, follow up right here.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick solution, I would assign the two cases to some holder boolean and act accordingly:

```
var angles = (angles.Count >= 2 && sides.Count >= 1);
var sides = (angles.Count == 1 && sides.Count >= 2);
if (angles)
{ calculateTriangleFromAngles(); }
else if (sides)
{ calculateTriangleFromAngles(); }
else
{ MsgBox.... }
```

As @user1012630 said, I used >= to cater for user giving more than two values for both angles and sides... You should add some edge cases if the user provides values for an impossible triangle of course.

Another sidenote: don't use `Convert.ToDouble()`, it will throw exception if the conversion fails. Better use `Double.TryParse()` to get a value or fail gracefully.

Comment: I need more than 2 calculations, my problem is that I don't know how to do it, if I have ASide, Bside and AAngle, or ASide, Bside and BAngle.
There should be alot of combinations and not just 2.